# Add key and value to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to add a new key/value pair to an (empty) dictionary. I have a text file with a string in it (years) and the script should count the appearances of the year.

```
    with open ("results/results_%s.txt" % bla, "r") as myfile:
       for line in myfile:
        line = line.translate(None, ''.join(chars_to_remove))
        abc = line.split("_", 2)
        year = abc[1:2]
        year = ''.join(year)
        year = year.translate(None, ''.join(chars_to_remove))
        raey = {}
        #increment the value of the "year"-key, if not present set it to 0 to avoid key erros
        raey[year] = raey.get(year, 0) + 1
```

However, if this returns for example {'2004': 1}, but It should have build a dictionary (like {1993 : 2, 2012 : 3} ), if I insert a "print" statement in the for loop I get for example:

```
{'1985': 1}
{'2062': 1}
{'1993': 1}
{'2000': 1}
{'2007': 1}
{'2009': 1}
{'1993': 1}
{'1998': 1}
{'1993': 1}
{'1998': 1}
{'2000': 1}
{'2013': 1}
{'1935': 1}
{'1999': 1}
{'1998': 1}
{'1992': 1}
{'1999': 1}
{'1818': 1}
{'2059': 1}
{'1990': 1}
```

It is not building a correct dict, the code is replacing the dict with every loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show the context of the results-file to help us? Create the dictionary outside of the loop, otherwise you will reset it with every cycle.

Comment: You are creating a new `raey`  dictionary each iteration with `raey = {}` . Put if before of the `for` statement.

Comment: Read up on the builtin [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module, especially [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are initializing the dict within the for loop, so a new one is created everytime. Instead, move it out

```
with open ("results/results_%s.txt" % bla, "r") as myfile:
  raey = {}
  for line in myfile:
    line = line.translate(None, ''.join(chars_to_remove))
    abc = line.split("_", 2)
    year = abc[1:2]
    year = ''.join(year)
    year = year.translate(None, ''.join(chars_to_remove))
    #increment the value of the "year"-key, if not present set it to 0 to avoid key erros
    raey[year] = raey.get(year, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Every iteration you call `raey = {}` which clears the dictionary. Move that line to before the loop to initialize the dictionary once and fill it in the loop.